# Nginx rewrite: replace trailing numbers with query string

Tags: url-rewriting, nginx

I'd like to achieve the following in Nginx:

```
/product/view/32 ---> /product/view?id=32
/product/add/32 ----> /product/add?id=32
/product/edit/32 ---> /product/edit?id=32
/post/view/32 ---> /post/view?id=32
/post/add/32 ----> /post/add?id=32
/post/edit/32 ---> /post/edit?id=32
/foo/bar/32 ---> /foo/bar?id=32
```

If you have a specific file in mind, then you can write something like this:

```
rewrite ^/path/(.*)$ /path/file.php?id=$1 last;
```

But how would you handle the case above, where you don't necessarily know the specific path?

Comment: You mean that you don't know which part of your path? You give three examples of redirects all with same path as `/product/`, yes? Can we be a little confused about that?

Comment: I wasn't clear. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give as three paths and they all have commont pattern `/product/` and you are saying that it's not necessarilly to know specific path so I can assume that you think about rest of your path. Then this what can change will be `view/32`, `/add/32` or `/edit/32`. In this case you can try such `rewrite` directive:

```
rewrite ^/product/([a-zA-Z]+)/[0-9]+) /product/$1?id=$2 last;
```

Here as variable `$1` you will get anything between `/product/` path and your id value. Variable `$2` will just represnted the `id` as a number at the end of your original paths.

---

**According to change in your question** it looks like there is always constant path which never changes after rewrite, for example:

When main path start with `/product/add` then you always rewrite it again as `/product/add`, if it is `/post/add` it will be also rewrited to `/post/add`. The only thing will change is your id from `/32` to `?id=32`. In this case we can achieve it the same way as first resolution but with one little change:

```
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)$ /$1?id=$2; last;
```

Here as variable `$1` will be set `product/view`, `product/add`, `post/edit`, `foo/bar` and all other cases matching pattern `([a-zA-Z]+/[a-zA-Z]+)`. For variable `$2` will be only set value of `id` staying at end of originaly url.

Comment: `/product/` is not a given in my URL scheme (I updated my question to reflect this), but I will always use this type of structure: `/<model>/<action>/<id>`.